# Scrapy Gives None as output

Tags: python, scrapy

I am hoping you could help me on a scraping script. 
From Chrome, I have confirmed the XPath is correct.

I am using XPATH selector for the script:

```
import scrapy

class SmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sm'

def start_requests(self):
    urls = []
    for i in range (0,10):
        urls.append('http://www.example.com/sm.php?a=view&recid='+str(i))
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):   
    companyname = response.selector.xpath('//table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').get()
    print(companyname)
```

`
BUT, when I try to output the Scraped Companyname I am get 'None'. I am not sure why this is the case. Could it be because of .php? Any workaropund I will appreciate

Comment: The reason that happens often is because the data is displayed from javascript (XHR request) and scrapy does not load javascript. There is two ways to find out, see the source of the page (ctrl+U on chrome), it will display the html without any javascript execution, if you cannot see any company name in the HTML it means data is loaded with javascript. Another way is to open dev console > Network and see if there is any XHR request that fetch the list of the company name.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom

Answer (score 1):

The range is starting from zero in your code, it's fine if intentional. Next you can use `response.xpath('//table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').extract()`.

```
import scrapy

class SmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sm'

def start_requests(self):
    urls = []
    for i in range (1,11):
        urls.append('http://www.example.com/sm.php?a=view&recid='+str(i))
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):   
    companyname = response.xpath('//table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]').extract()
    print(companyname)
```

If my answer is wrong, please provide the URL for the page you wish to scrape for better answer.